# Add a span tag to text inside a hyperlink, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How would you add a span tag to the text inside a hyperlink?

Right now, I'm changing the existing text to something else, using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a:contains('text')").text('new-text')
});
```

I need the link to look like this when it is parsed:

```
<a href="/xxx.aspx">new-text<span class="someclass">some other text</span></a>
```

So I need to add that span tag inside the

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("a:contains('text')")
    .text('new-text')
    .append($('<span></span>')
        .addClass('someclass')
        .text('some other text')
    )
;
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `html()` method to add a markup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:contains('text')").html('new-text<span class="someclass">some other text</span>')
});
```