# Can I get highlighted text with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I'm not finding anything anywhere.  Is there a JQuery solution to retrieve highlighted text?  I need to check the highlighted text for spans, get those spans' style attributes, and manipulate them based on that.  I can do that part with regular expressions or whatever obviously, but first I need access to the highlighted text!  I'm struggling to even find a cross-browser plain javascript solution, so if you've got one of those handy that would help immensely as well.

Thanks!

Comment: There are *tons* of duplicates of this question. Use Google.

Comment: I found a ton of results with Google, but none of them actually seemed to work cross-browser.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You mean text selection with mouse, so check here, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GYuBv/2/

```
$('#showSelected').on('click', function(){

    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    alert(text);       
});
```

If you want to do some changes around selected text, check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GYuBv/3/

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate the text in/around the selection?

Comment: here is a sample, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GYuBv/3/

Comment: The deed has been done.  This was quite helpful, but is there also a way to manipulate the text in other ways?  I'd like to be able to replace things in the text, check it for specific strings, and manipulate it the way I could anything else.  I tried adding ".toString()" at the end of the 'w' var and manipulating it from there to no avail.

Comment: Check this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095829/add-a-span-tag-to-text-inside-a-hyperlink-using-jquery, you can get an idea

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GYuBv/4/, you can use .html() to play around with your selected text.

Comment: It's very good, but doesn't seem to work across markup boundaries - this solution does though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304837/javascript-user-selection-highlighting#12823606