# How to focus multiple selected line in contenteditable div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable, execcommand

When i try to given below code for change `margin-bottom` of selected multiple line, at that time only last selected line was change other line just add p tag but not the style. May be i can not focus all selected line.I tried below code for this.

**Javascript:**

```
var selectedElement = null;
function singleline() {
    document.execCommand('formatblock',false,'p')
    selectedElement1 = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
    selectedElement1.style.marginBottom = '10px';                
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="addMarginBottom" onclick="javascript:singleline();"/>
<div class="textcontent" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**My problem is:** How can i focus all selected node and add this style?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS for single line and multiple line focus the code is -

```
           $(document).ready(function()
            {
                document.execCommand('formatblock',false,'p') 
              // for multiple line focus
                var selectedNodes = [];
                var sel = rangy.getSelection();
                for (var i = 0; i < sel.rangeCount; ++i) {
                    selectedNodes = selectedNodes.concat( sel.getRangeAt(i).getNodes() );
                    $(selectedNodes).css("height","40px");   

                }

                // single line focus
                 var  selectedElement = null;
                selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
                $(selectedElement).css("height","40px");
});
```

It works for me. Hopefully you also get help from this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GYuBv/149/

```
function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
        }

        var nNd = document.createElement("span");
        var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        w.surroundContents(nNd);
        return nNd.innerHTML;
    } catch (e) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return document.selection.createRange();
        } else {
            return getSelection();
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('#changeColor').click( function() {
        var mytext = selectHTML();
        $('span').css({"margin-bottom":"10px"});
    });
});
```

Was an answer from here: [Can I get highlighted text with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227070/can-i-get-highlighted-text-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
 var selectedNodes = [];
                var sel = rangy.getSelection();
                for (var i = 0; i < sel.rangeCount; i++) {
                    selectedNodes = selectedNodes.concat( sel.getRangeAt(i).getNodes() );
                    $(selectedNodes).css("height","20px");

                    }
```