# Target entire body when using select

Tags: jquery

I am making a web page and i want to get the highlighted text. Problem is,i want to do something when a user highlights text anywhere within the page.

I have this

```
$("body").select( function (e) { 
        alert("You selected: "+window.getSelection());
    });
```

here https://jsfiddle.net/xn9mnmy1/

but it does not seem to work.

What could i be doing wrong?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get highlighted text with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227070/can-i-get-highlighted-text-with-jquery)

Comment: There is no `select` event. Try `mouseup`: https://jsfiddle.net/xn9mnmy1/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', function(){

    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    alert(text);       
});
```

Source: [Can I get highlighted text with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227070/can-i-get-highlighted-text-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.click()` method you can send the selected text as an alert to the user.

You have to make sure if the selected text string is **not empty** before calling `alert()` or you will get an alert every time you click anywhere.

```
$('body').click(readText);

function readText(){
    var text = window.getSelection().toString();
    if(text.length > 0){
            alert("You selected:\n" + text);
        }  
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/r24b0dpv/

Answer (score -1):

Straight from [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/select/):

This event is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes.