# Drag and drop a word or phrase from a block of text using HTML5/CSS3/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to make an educational web app that helps people identify key phrases in the text. The user would select a word(s) out of a paragraph with a mouse or finger. Now drag n drop is a [standard feature](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_draganddrop.asp), my issue is I would need to preprocess the paragraph into chunks ala

```
<P>
   <span> This is not important</span>
   <span> This is important</span>
   <span> This is not important</span>
<p>
```

Now I can apply CSS and whatever to these chunks, but I would correlate the difficulty to how coarse the chunking would be. Ideally I would like the ability to select any set of words and be able to pull a chunk based on what the user highlights not how I chunk. The only idea I have in how to do this would be the absurdity of

```
<p>
  <span>Tommy</span><span> buys </span><span> 2 </span><span> apples.</span>
<p>
```

In the example above I would want to the user to define the chunk by highlight any number of words. So the user could chunk

Tom buys 2 apples,
Tom buys, 
2 apples,
buys 2 apples, 
etc...

I would enforce the word phrase to be connected aka Tom apples would not be valid. Once selected I would apply a drag-drop & highlighting features to the chunk. I am hoping there is a more elegant way to do this. I hope this was a clear enough description of what I intended.

Thanks in advance.

***update***

I alluded to my approach in my original text and below is what I was referring too which is adaptation of what is in the link. I do not think I should be down voted for this post.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <span id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is not 
important</span><br>
  <span id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is 
important</span><br>
  <span id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">This is not 
imporant</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: While this is an interesting problem you're trying to solve, you should attempt to solve it on your own first instead of asking SO to do the work for you.

Comment: take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227070/can-i-get-highlighted-text-with-jquery there someone anwsered how to get the selected text of the user.. If im right you then only have to make that draggable..

Comment: @UllasHunka I updated my post but it is not much different from the W3schools. I am looking for a pathway that makes this feasible. My current approach does not scale.

Comment: @Bucket I did, and it is now posted.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice I tried giving it another go but it seems like this is too in-depth for me. I updated my code so it doesnt validate immediately but then upon further investigation I found a loophole, so I decided to scrap the whole thing since it didn't seem of any value to the situation. Sorry I couldn't help any further. I'm sure someone else will pick up on this.